# Failed to convert from Activity to Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I was trying to convert my Activity class into Fragment class, because I want my Activity page to run on a fragment page. This is my Activity class before I change anything:

```
public class People extends Activity {

ImageButton img_btn_save, img_btn_load, img_btn_edit, img_btn_delete; 
EditText et_name, et_amount, et_description;
ListView lv_people_info;
String name, amount, description;
OwesomeDBHelper mOwesomeDBHelper;
SQLiteDatabase db;

private String[] allColumns = { PeopleEntry._ID,
        PeopleEntry.COLUMN_NAME, PeopleEntry.COLUMN_AMOUNT, PeopleEntry.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION};

ArrayList<String> people_info;
ArrayList<String> people_info2;

String selection_delete_where = PeopleEntry.COLUMN_NAME + " LIKE ?";

String[] selectionArgs_delete_where;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_people);

    img_btn_save = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.img_btn_people_save);
    img_btn_load = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.img_btn_people_load);
    img_btn_edit = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.img_btn_people_edit);
    img_btn_delete = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.img_btn_people_delete);

    et_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_people_name);
    et_amount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_people_amount);
    et_description = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_people_description);

    lv_people_info =(ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_people);

    mOwesomeDBHelper = new OwesomeDBHelper(this);
    db = mOwesomeDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    refresh();

    img_btn_save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            name = et_name.getText().toString();
            amount = et_amount.getText().toString();
            description = et_description.getText().toString();

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(PeopleEntry.COLUMN_NAME, name);
            values.put(PeopleEntry.COLUMN_AMOUNT, amount);
            values.put(PeopleEntry.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, description);

            insertData (db, values);

            et_name.setText(null);
            et_amount.setText(null);
            et_description.setText(null);

            refresh();
        }
    });

    img_btn_edit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(PeopleEntry.COLUMN_AMOUNT, et_amount.getText().toString());
            values.put(PeopleEntry.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, et_description.getText().toString());

            String selection_update = PeopleEntry.COLUMN_NAME + " LIKE ?";
            String[] selectionArgs_update = new String[] { et_name.getText().toString() };

            int count = db.update(PeopleEntry.TABLE_NAME, values,
                    selection_update, selectionArgs_update);

            Message.message(getApplicationContext(), count + ": Record Updated");

            refresh();  
        }
    });


    img_btn_delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
            selectionArgs_delete_where = new String[] { et_name.getText().toString()};

            db.delete(PeopleEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                    selection_delete_where,
                    selectionArgs_delete_where);

            et_name.setText(null);
            et_amount.setText(null);
            et_description.setText(null);

            Message.message(getApplicationContext(), "Record Deleted"); 
            refresh();
        }
    });


}

public void refresh(){
    people_info = new ArrayList<String>();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(PeopleEntry.TABLE_NAME,// Table
            allColumns, // The columns to return
            null, // The columns for the WHERE clause
            null, // The values for the WHERE clause
            null, // don't group the rows
            null, // don't filter by row groups
            null, // The sort order
            null); // Limits the number of rows returned by the  query  

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        people_info.add(" \n" + cursor.getString(0) + ". Name: "
            + cursor.getString(1) + " \n     Amount (RM): "
            + cursor.getString(2) + " \n     Description: "
            + cursor.getString(3) + " \n");
            cursor.moveToNext();
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getApplicationContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, people_info);

    lv_people_info.setAdapter(adapter);
        cursor.close();
}

public void insertData(SQLiteDatabase db, ContentValues values) {
    long newRowId;
    newRowId = db.insert(PeopleEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values);

    if (newRowId != -1) {
        Message.message(this, "New Data Inserted");
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.people, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}}
```

The code runs just fine, however, when I try to convert it to Fragment, there seem to be errors. This is my attempted Fragment code:

```
public class People extends Fragment {

ImageButton img_btn_save, img_btn_load, img_btn_edit, img_btn_delete; 
EditText et_name, et_amount, et_description;
ListView lv_people_info;
String name, amount, description;
OwesomeDBHelper mOwesomeDBHelper;
SQLiteDatabase db;

//Store columns in array
private String[] allColumns = { PeopleEntry._ID,
        PeopleEntry.COLUMN_NAME, PeopleEntry.COLUMN_AMOUNT, PeopleEntry.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION};

//Declare array list for list view
ArrayList<String> people_info;
ArrayList<String> people_info2;

// Define 'where' part of query.
String selection_delete_where = PeopleEntry.COLUMN_NAME + " LIKE ?";

// Specify arguments in placeholder order.
String[] selectionArgs_delete_where;

public People(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_people, container, false);

    FragmentActivity    faActivity  = (FragmentActivity)    super.getActivity();

 // Replace LinearLayout by the type of the root element of the layout you're trying to load
    LinearLayout        llLayout    = (LinearLayout)    inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_people, container, false);

    img_btn_save = (ImageButton) llLayout.findViewById(R.id.img_btn_people_save);
    img_btn_load = (ImageButton) llLayout.findViewById(R.id.img_btn_people_load);
    img_btn_edit = (ImageButton) llLayout.findViewById(R.id.img_btn_people_edit);
    img_btn_delete = (ImageButton) llLayout.findViewById(R.id.img_btn_people_delete);

    et_name = (EditText) llLayout.findViewById(R.id.et_people_name);
    et_amount = (EditText) llLayout.findViewById(R.id.et_people_amount);
    et_description = (EditText) llLayout.findViewById(R.id.et_people_description);

    lv_people_info =(ListView) llLayout.findViewById(R.id.lv_people);

    mOwesomeDBHelper = new OwesomeDBHelper(super.getActivity());
    db = mOwesomeDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    refresh();

    img_btn_save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            name = et_name.getText().toString();
            amount = et_amount.getText().toString();
            description = et_description.getText().toString();

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(PeopleEntry.COLUMN_NAME, name);
            values.put(PeopleEntry.COLUMN_AMOUNT, amount);
            values.put(PeopleEntry.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, description);

            insertData (db, values);

            et_name.setText(null);
            et_amount.setText(null);
            et_description.setText(null);

            refresh();
        }
    });

    img_btn_edit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(PeopleEntry.COLUMN_AMOUNT, et_amount.getText().toString());
            values.put(PeopleEntry.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, et_description.getText().toString());
            // Which row to update, based on the name
            String selection_update = PeopleEntry.COLUMN_NAME + " LIKE ?";
            String[] selectionArgs_update = new String[] { et_name.getText().toString() };

            int count = db.update(PeopleEntry.TABLE_NAME, values,
                    selection_update, selectionArgs_update);

            Message.message(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), count + ": Record Updated");

            refresh();  
        }
    });


    img_btn_delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
            selectionArgs_delete_where = new String[] { et_name.getText().toString()};

            db.delete(PeopleEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                    selection_delete_where,
                    selectionArgs_delete_where);

            et_name.setText(null);
            et_amount.setText(null);
            et_description.setText(null);

            Message.message(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Record Deleted");   
            refresh();
        }           
    });

    //// I get error on either one of these:
    return rootView;
    return llLayout;

}

public void refresh(){
    people_info = new ArrayList<String>();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(PeopleEntry.TABLE_NAME,// Table
            allColumns, // The columns to return
            null, // The columns for the WHERE clause
            null, // The values for the WHERE clause
            null, // don't group the rows
            null, // don't filter by row groups
            null, // The sort order
            null); // Limits the number of rows returned by the  query  

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        people_info.add(" \n" + cursor.getString(0) + ". Name: "
            + cursor.getString(1) + " \n     Amount (RM): "
            + cursor.getString(2) + " \n     Description: "
            + cursor.getString(3) + " \n");
            cursor.moveToNext();
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, people_info);

    lv_people_info.setAdapter(adapter);
        cursor.close();
}

public void insertData(SQLiteDatabase db, ContentValues values) {
    long newRowId;
    newRowId = db.insert(PeopleEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values);

    if (newRowId != -1) {
        Message.message(super.getActivity(), "New Data Inserted");
    }

}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    /////// I suddenly get red underline on "people"
    getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.people, menu);
    //return true;
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}}
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: can you add some more info on the errors you're getting?

Comment: In `onCreateOptionsMenu`, you don't need to inflate the Activity's menu. The activity containing the Fragment should do that. The Fragment's menu and Activity's menu will be merged if you have 2 separate menus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to add this code

```
LinearLayout llLayout = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_people, container, false);
```

because you've already done with

```
 View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_people, container, false);
```

So remove

```
 LinearLayout llLayout = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_people, container, false);
```

Also in return statement remove

```
 return llLayout;
```

Also no need to use `super.getActivity()`. In `Fragment` just call `getActivity()` as a `Context`.

**EDIT:**

Simply you need to change this

```
getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.people, menu);
```

to

```
inflater.inflate(R.menu.people, menu);
```

Comment: Dont forget replacing all `llLayout.findViewById` with `rootView.findViewById`

Comment: You should replace all all `llLayout.findViewById`with `rootView.findViewById`

Comment: Thanks. But I also get an error at "people" on  getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.people, menu); do you know why this happens?

Comment: Is people layout added in menu folder? Check my edited answer @MayaRehan

Comment: I changed it just like your edit. I no longer have any errors, but my application crashes with java.lang.ClassCastException: info.owesome.slidingmenu(my package name).MainActivity cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity

Comment: Is your MainActivity extends with FragmentActivity?